# What is the equivalent /proc/process_pid/environ file in AIX?

Tags: environment-variables, aix

Usually I look this file in Linux using `string -a` command to see this file.

Has AIX something like that? I didn't find anything in `/proc/pid_process`

I use this file to know what environment variables some process is seeing.

for example, I have an Oracle Database installed on the server. If I'd like to know what environment variable `pmon` process is seeing, I can find the process:

```
[root@oracle-database 1664]# ps aux|grep pmon|grep -v grep
oracle    8897  0.0  0.5 1133456 5312 ?        Ss   Nov27   0:18 ora_pmon_idbcloud
[root@oracle-database 1664]#
```

And look the file `/proc/process_pid/environ`

```
[root@oracle-database 1664]# strings -a /proc/8897/environ
XDG_SESSION_ID=4689
HOSTNAME=oracle-database
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
HISTSIZE=1000
USER=oracle
ORACLE_SID=idbcloud
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/oracle
PATH=
PWD=/u01
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/oracle
LOGNAME=oracle
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1
NLS_DATE_FORMAT=DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS
_=/bin/rlwrap
OLDPWD=/u01
ORA_NET2_DESC=9,12
SKGP_SPAWN_DIAG_POST_FORK_TS=1606503159
SKGP_HIDDEN_ARGS=<FATAL/S/PMON/x0/x1/x0/x5AF86E15/8888/8888/x0/x2/x1/x5AF86E38/1606503159/1606503159/196609/0/(nil)>
SKGP_SPAWN_DIAG_PRE_FORK_TS=1606503159
SKGP_SPAWN_DIAG_PRE_EXEC_TS=1606503159
ORACLE_SPAWNED_PROCESS=1
RDMAV_FORK_SAFE=1
RDMAV_HUGEPAGES_SAFE=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Thomas said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622810/117549), there is no *file* in an AIX system, but the [`ps` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/p_commands/ps.html) *does* let you "know what environment variables some process is seeing"

```
e
    Displays the environment as well as the parameters to the command, up to a limit of 80 characters.
ew
     Wraps the display from the e flag one extra line.
eww
     Wraps the display from the e flag and displays the ENV list until the flag reaches the LINE_MAX value.
ewww
     Wraps the display from the e flag and displays the ENV list until the flag reaches the INT_MAX value.
```

For example:

```
$ ps ewww 1835516
      PID    TTY STAT  TIME COMMAND
  1835516      - A     7:02 /usr/sbin/syncd 60 _=/usr/bin/nohup LANG=C PATH=/usr/sbin:/etc:/usr/bin LC__FASTMSG=true ODMDIR=/etc/objrepos HOME=/ PWD=/ CFGLOG=default NLSPATH=/usr/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N:/usr/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat LIBPATH=/usr/lib:/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

AIX does not provide the same style of pseudo-filesystem for `/proc` as Linux does.  Referring to the manual pages:

- [**`/proc`** file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/filesreference/proc.html) (AIX)
- [proc - process information pseudo-filesystem](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (Linux)

the latter documents a pseudo-file dedicated to environment:

```
   /proc/[pid]/environ
          This file contains the initial environment that was set when
          the currently executing program was started via execve(2).
```

while the former describes a file containing process information

> ***psinfo***
> Contains information about the process needed by the ***ps*** command. If the process contains more than one thread, a representative thread is used to derive the *lwpsinfo* information. The file is formatted as a **`struct psinfo`** type and contains the following members:

In particular:

```
prptr64_t   pr_envp;                /* address of initial environment vector
                                       in user process */
```

While it is possible to write a *script* which reads that data structure, you will not do it with just **`grep`** or **`strings`**: that address would be used in accessing the memory image file:

> ***as***
> Contains the address space image of the process. The ***as*** file can be opened for both reading and writing. The **`lseek`** subroutine is used to position the file at the virtual address of interest. Afterwards, you can view and modify the address space with the read and write subroutines, respectively.